# arccos in c (without using acos)

Tags: c

I got a questions that requires me to use cosine and fabs to write codes that calculates an arccos of a value. The thing is, I've been looking online for a while now and all the formulas either just use a unit circle or a different inverse function, which doesn't help my situation. How do I calculate arccos by using cos and fabs without using acos?

Comment: I guess you could do a binary search.

Answer (score 1):

You *could* use a binary search for this.

Since the arccos (or inverse cosine, or cos<sup>-1</sup>) is defined as:

```
arccos(x) = λ when cos(λ) = x, 0 <= λ <= π, -1 <= x <= 1
```

Simply start your bounds at `0` and `π`, and run the search as per the following Python (the ideal pseudo-code language):

```
import math

def myArcCos(x):
    # Everything is radians, I have no time for sexagesimal rubbish :-)
    # Also, don't waste my time with values outside the domain.

    if x < -1 or x > 1 : return None

    # Handle special cases first, to ensure binary search not needed.

    if x == -1: return math.pi
    if x ==  0: return math.pi / 2
    if x ==  1: return 0

    # Close enough is good enough :-) - avoid FP imprecision.

    closeEnough = 1e-10

    # Starting point for binary search.

    low = 0
    high = math.pi

    while True:
        mid = (high + low) / 2
        cosmid = math.cos(mid)

        # If close enough, return value.

        if abs(x - cosmid) <= closeEnough:
            return mid

        # Otherwise adjust range and continue.

        if cosmid > x:
            low = mid
        else:
            high = mid

# Test program to do 0..pi in 2000 steps. Yes, I know I use acos()
# Here but that's just for testing. The actual solution (see
# above) uses only abs(), cos(), and pi.

for x in range(-1000, 1001):
    value = x / 1000
    actual = math.acos(value)
    mine = myArcCos(value)
    print(actual, mine, abs(actual - mine))
```

The output of that is, with the three values in each line being the real acos, my calculated acos, and the absolute difference between them:

```
3.141592653589793 3.141592653589793 0.0
3.09686756642106 3.0968675672047086 7.836487014856175e-10
3.07833655471465 3.0783365556794116 9.647616039387685e-10
3.064113608665912 3.0641136096823347 1.0164225017206263e-09
3.0521200933852985 3.0521200923213394 1.0639591430106066e-09
3.041550939978253 3.041550939296549 6.81704026561647e-10
3.031993295758154 3.0319932961080616 3.4990765840348104e-10
3.0232019280620164 3.023201927946575 1.1544143418973363e-10
3.015017067627069 3.0150170680657356 4.386664365085835e-10
3.0073277475716567 3.0073277482775596 7.059028916955867e-10
3.000053180265366 3.000053180394036 1.286699635727473e-10
2.9931323825931333 2.9931323826750322 8.189893208054855e-11
2.9865179806254547 2.986517979981468 6.439866417906615e-10
2.9801723034413645 2.9801723036357197 1.9435519860167005e-10
2.9740648100904594 2.9740648101026705 1.2211121003247172e-11
2.968170332494189 2.968170332071144 4.2304471037368785e-10
2.9624678387109036 2.9624678386308316 8.007194907122539e-11
2.956939539764772 2.9569395392349707 5.298015359755937e-10
2.9515702301270825 2.951570230507425 3.803424242221354e-10
2.946346791223863 2.9463467908044807 4.193823066600544e-10
2.9412578112666736 2.9412578108280387 4.3863490617468415e-10
2.9362932897368528 2.9362932900701084 3.3325564530173324e-10
2.931444404565336 2.931444404208834 3.565019390805446e-10
2.9267033264796236 2.9267033266324938 1.528701609743166e-10
2.9220630693398637 2.9220630689814233 3.5844038848154014e-10
2.917517368287974 2.917517368503323 2.1534907190812191e-10
2.913060579642169 2.9130605797973277 1.5515855267267398e-10
2.908687597974201 2.9086875980107982 3.659739178374366e-11
2.904393786896605 2.904393787156341 2.5973578843263567e-10
... hundreds and hundreds of more lines, all with diffs around 10^-10
```